# 平成２９年７月２７日　東京・渋谷での開発者交流会

Tags: 討議, 完了, 交流会

【このイベントは終了しました】

---

当社の開発者とプログラミングについて話しませんか？

当社の開発者[konamiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/4574)が来日します。せっかくなので、日本のスタックオーバーフローユーザーとの交流会を開催したいと思います！

- **場所：** 東京・渋谷駅辺り（おおよその人数が把握できてからお店を決めるので、後日またみなさんにお知らせします）
- **時間：** １９時〜２１時
- **費用：** 無料

飲物・軽食はこちらで準備します。興味がある方は[こちらの無料チケットをゲットしてください！[ぜひお早めに！！](http://peatix.com/event/281076)。

konamimanについて：

> 1985年のクリスマス、11歳の頃にkonamimanは初めてのパソコンを手に入れました。[MSX](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX)の[Canon V-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_V-20)でした。はじめはゲームをするだけのために利用していましが、数年後、BASICでのプログラミングからassemblyに興味をもちました。
>
> 最終的にはメーカーもユーザーもMSXパソコン（PC・Mac以外のパソコン）のサポート・利用を終了したのですが、一部のユーザーのために新しいハードウェアやソフトウェアが現在も作られています。konamimanもそのユーザーの仲間になって、[assemblyのみで作られたTCP/IPスタック](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#inl)、[NextorOS](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#nextor)等のMSXソフトを作成しました。
>
> 1997年にkonamimanはインターネットを通じて日本人の女性と出会いました。日本語の練習相手をさがしていたkonamimanの妹が偶然に彼女と出会い、その6年後にkonamimanはその彼女と結婚しました。現在スペインに住んでいますが、年に一度は日本に帰国しています。
>
> 2002年よりプロの開発者として勤務しています。[Stack Overflow en
>
>   Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)のベータ時代にモデレーターとして活躍した後、2016年にはStack OverflowのCore Developerになり、スペインからリモートで働いています。
>
> 関連情報（英語・スペイン語）：
>
> - [MSXサイト](http://www.konamiman.com)
> - [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/konamiman)
> - [Konamiman's talk about his TCP/IP stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJomQNEgbww)

質問等ありましたら、お気軽にお問い合わせください！

---

開催場所が決定しました！
（申し込みが未だの方はできるだけ早くお願いします。）

場所：くいもの屋わん 渋谷文化村通り店

https://r.gnavi.co.jp/a127657/

●住所
〒150-0042 東京都渋谷区宇田川町34-5 サイトービルⅢ 3F

●アクセス
ＪＲ 渋谷駅 ハチ公口 徒歩5分

みなさんにお会いできますこと、楽しみにしております！！