# 5/31(金)東京・渋谷でMeetUpを開催します　→　しました！

Tags: 討議, 交流会

**追記：令和元年5月31日(金)の夜に東京・渋谷で開催しました！**

ご参加頂いた皆さんへ：
お忙しい中お集まり頂きまして本当にありがとうございました素敵な集合写真やLTのスライドが共有されたことによって、今回は参加できなかった日本全国そして世界各国よりSOjaを利用するユーザーの方々も東京MeetUpをさらに身近に感じることができたのではないかと思います。

LT発表者の[Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)さんと[payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)さん、ご参加頂いた皆さん、そして第一回目のユーザー主催イベントを大成功に導いた司会者兼LT発表者の[nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)さんに、改めてお礼を申し上げたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

素晴らしいLT発表資料たち
 1. 「[モデレーターって何？](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1D6awJp9zWIKeJwTCMotPQsJcMEA4E8b8bzC19IJgV4g/edit#slide=id.p)」by nekketsuuuさん
 2. 「[世界でn番目に頭の〇いStack Exchangeのつかいかた](https://payaneco.github.io/so_meetsup_2019_tokyo/#/)」by payanecoさん
 3. 「[SO で質問しよう](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MBfuOscwBhAe92UQ5STSHkQt1Z5sJYQZR1ydRr_c3DQ/edit#slide=id.g5adabddf1f_0_0)」by Yuki Inoueさん

今後もこのような[ユーザー主催のイベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3017/14055)を通じてコミュニティのつながりを大切に保つことができればと思っています。そして、日本語を話すプログラマーの皆さんにとってスタック・オーバーフローが「居心地の良い場所」になるよう、できる限りサポートして参りますのでどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

詳細：https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2996/19110

---

こちらのSOjaステッカーがサンクトペテルブルクから無事届きました。東京MeetUp参加者のみなさん、nekketsuuuさんが当日お配りくださいますので楽しみにしていてくださいねー
[image: ロシアより愛をこめて]

尚、東京以外のMeetUp開催についてはこちらを！
→ [希望者募集中：東京以外の場所でMeetUpを開催したい方はいらっしゃいますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3000/19110)
もしも東京以外での開催希望者が多くない場合、次回も東京開催がよろしいでしょうか..？大型連休で名古屋や関西からも参加可能な日程にする、など？

---

前回の開発者交流会は[2年前に開催されたよう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2521/78)です。そして日本では元号が変わり、新しい時代が幕を開けようとしています。そろそろスタック・オーバーフローMeetUpを開催しませんか？

5月の中頃に東京開催のMeetUpに参加できるユーザーが何人かいると聞きました。しかしMeetUpの日時や開催場所、スタイル等はまだ未定です。どこでどのようなMeetUpに参加できるのかをどうぞコミュニティで共有してください。あなたが参加したいMeetUpとはどのようなスタイルでしょうか？あなたが描くスタック・オーバーフローのMeetUpとはどのようなものでしょうか？

こちらのメタ投稿の回答欄に加えて、[Googleフォームに詳細を記入して](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBHkXQcrVGECCTSFbHfxsdGHtv76VK0lPAWbk0LaDrqK-pGA/viewform)ください。 効率的良くみなさんのご意見をまとめられればと思います。

Answer (score 14):

### 追記：開催しました！

2019年5月31日、MeetUpを開催しました！　個人的にも楽しい会になったと思います。LTしてくださった方々、参加してくださった方々、お店とのやりとりをしてくださったakiさん、お店の方々、どうもありがとうございました。

当日の様子はTwitterで [#スタック・オーバーフローMeetUp](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%23%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BCMeetUp%20until%3A2019-06-02) で検索すると何となく分かります。また、LTの資料がconnpassに上がっておりますので、ご覧くださいませ。

https://soja.connpass.com/event/130838/

[image: お店の前に飾られたウェルカムボードです。]

[image: 皆さんの集合写真です。]

### 以下、開催前の情報です

2019年5月31日(金)の夜に東京・渋谷でMeetUpを開催します

https://soja.connpass.com/event/130838/（申込みは締切りました）

以下、connpassに掲載した説明文からの抜粋です。

---

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティの皆さんで交流会を行います！

令和初のプレミアムフライデー、ご飯にライトニングトークを挟みつつスタック・オーバーフローの話題を共有しましょう。

#### 場所

東京・渋谷でプロジェクターが使えるお店を予約しました。

https://www.hotpepper.jp/strJ000001371/

#### ライトニングトーク

スタック・オーバーフローや Stack Exchange に関係する話題で、5分程度のライトニングトーク (LT) をしてくださる方を募集します！

たとえば、以下のような話題は如何でしょうか？

- スタック・オーバーフローに参加してみての感想や戸惑ったことなど
- 好きな質問・回答の紹介
- +1投票されやすい質問・回答の書き方のコツの解説
- 面白いメタ投稿の紹介
- 判断に困った事例の共有
- あまり知られていない仕組みの紹介
- 他の Stack Exchange サイトの紹介
- 他の質問サイトとの比較

#### LTタイムテーブル

19:15～  nekketsuuu  「モデレーターって何？」
19:25～  mogutan88   「スタックオーバーフローと日本文化」
19:35～  payaneco    「世界でn番目に頭の〇いStack Exchangeのつかいかた」
19:45～  Yuki Inoue  「SO で質問しよう」

#### 参加者プレゼント

[image: t-shirts etc...]

スタック・オーバーフローオリジナルステッカーやTシャツ -> 参加者全員
Koozie（オレンジ色のドリンクホルダー）-> LT発表者

などを準備しております(((o(*ﾟ▽ﾟ*)o)))

[image: メンダコのぬいぐるみとTシャツ]
写真提供：[sayuri](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4236/sayuri)さん
東京MeetUpに参加すると、おみやげとしてこのようなTシャツがもらえます。
（メンダコのぬいぐるみは...もらえないのですが）

#### お食事メニュー等

★アンチョビ入りスタッフドオリーブ
★アボカドとクリームチーズのカナッペ
★鮮魚のカルパッチョ
★彩り野菜のヘルシーサラダ
★フライドポテト～明太クリームディップ～
★グリルチキン～ペッパークリームソース～
★ピザ　マルゲリータ
苦手な食材がある方はお知らせ下さい。
飲み放題です。

未成年の方も参加できますが、その際は必ずMeetUpリードの@nekketsuuuさんにお声がけくださいますようお願い申し上げます。

Comment: メタの、タイトルを更新して、サイトを訪れた人に、今絶賛 connpass 予約募集中であることを明示すると、よいかもしれません。 (Featured Post 的な意味で) (編集しました)

Comment: 評価最上位で上に来てるので問題は無いのかなぁとも思いますが、質問(議題)本文の上の方にconnpassフォームを入れた方が良いのかも？

Comment: @Sieg さん、ありがとうございます、追加してみました :)

Comment: 今アクセスしたら、connpassがメンテナンスで入れないですね。

Comment: 「5/15(水) 13:30から3時間ほどメンテナンスの予定」だそうです。 - https://twitter.com/connpass_jp

Comment: 絵と物語をどうもありがとうございました！来てくれた皆さんありがとう。すごいね！

Answer (score 5):

行ける日付を1日だけ選ぶスタイルだとなかなか予定が集まらないでしょうから、どなたかがパシッと1日決めてもらって、その日に来れる／来れないで選ぶと良いのではないかと思いました。

予定が決まった後の出席調整は、connpass を使うのはいかがでしょうか: https://connpass.com/。個人的に慣れているというだけです。前回は Peatix を使ったようなので、それでも良いとは思います。

MeetUpの形式としては、ビアバッシュで、ライトニングトークがあったりなかったりするくらいが良いのかなあと思っておりました。ライトニングトークありの場合は、テーマがあると話しやすそうです。「印象的だったQ&A」や「紹介したいメタ投稿」みたいな。

Comment: フィードバックをありがとうございました！私はあなたが正しいと思います。何日か選ぶ必要があります。会議を開催するためにサイトを使用することは素晴らしいアイデアです。 しばらく考えてみましょう。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん　「ビアバッシュでLTがあったりなかったりするくらい」良いと思います！そろそろお店を確定できればと...。(何でも部屋チャットなど？)

Comment: 今後はconnpassを使用することになりました

Answer (score 2):

5月中旬とのことでGWのような大型連休をすぎた後に開催するのかぁという率直な感想です。

開催は出来るだけ早いほうがいいのでしょうか？
開催のスパンは長いですし夏頃とか大型連休のほうが都合が良いのではないかなぁと思ってます。

近場にいる人とか、閑散期に入っている社会人とかじゃないと参加できなくて、
遠方の方とか、学生はきっと参加が難しいでしょうね。

バシッと日付を誰かが決めると、決めた人基準になってしまうのでちょっとなぁって感じです。
今のアンケート方式は割と賛成派です。
ただ、アンケート期限を設けた方が良いですね。

Comment: フィードバックをありがとうございました！日付について考えさせてください。

Comment: @Sieg さん、ご意見まことにありがとうございます！名古屋でのミートアップ を是非今年開催したいと思っておりますが、夏頃もしくは秋のシルバーウィークあたりはいかがでしょうか？名古屋開催のお声は東京開催に比べて少なかったため、少し先の方がプラニングする時間も設けられて良いのではないかと思いました。

Comment: 確かに名古屋は立地的に東海三県か大阪・東京以外のところからだとアクセスが不便なところがあるので大阪か東京が一般的だと確かに思います。(大阪・東京からのアクセスはしやすくあるのですが…)
私としては名古屋など東海地方ですと参加しやすくはあるのですが、シルバーウィークであれば別地方にもいけると思いますので、他の方の意見も聞いてみたく思います。

Comment: 過去のMETA投稿の修正を見てたのですが、これ開催されると令和元年(1年)の開催になるんですね。なんか感慨深いです。