# スタック・オーバーフローにおける「ロボットではない」バッジについて

Tags: 討議, 交流会, バッジ

[nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)、[cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)に翻訳してくれてありがとう

---

昨日 [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) がスタック・オーバーフローにおいて [ロボットではない](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win) バッジを有効にしたことを共有できて嬉しく思います。 (英語版での)バッジの説明では以下が獲得条件になっています。

> Stack Overflowが主催者または参加者だった参加者50人以上のイベントで、Stack Overflowの従業員と会いました。このバッジは何回でも獲得できます。

[Juan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/296470/juan-m) と [私(Nicolas)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky) は、バッジの背景にある理由と、スタック・オーバーフローでこのバッジをより活性化していく方法について議論しました。 ユーザーが主催するコミュニティの交流会は、その他のカンファレンスのように形式張る必要はないと我々は思います。結果として、私たちはお互いを知るユーザーによって計画された交流会に参加する人々に [ロボットではない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/not-a-robot) バッジを付与するつもりでいます。

---

[5月31日に東京で開催された交流会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/78) に参加してくれたユーザーにもう一度「ありがとう」と言わせてください。参加者全員が [バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/not-a-robot) を獲得しました。

おめでとうございます！

Comment: バッジの説明文の訳については [チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50629993#50629993) でも話が出ていましたが、恐らく本来の条件より緩和して付与してくれたのであろう事を踏まえて、この場では両方とも「Stack Overflow」のままにしておきました。

Comment: いつか参加者50人以上のイベントがあるといいですね。

Comment: 50人以上のイベントは、パブリックベータ卒業時に開催されるのではないでしょうか